# Disable UITextView when end of line is reached

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I created a 'UITextView' and instead of setting Maximum Character Limit, I want the keyboard to be disabled when the characters reached the end of the line. I tried researching but I can't find an answer. Seems like I am the first one to ask the question.

Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: would a UITextField work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

 NSMutableString * mutableString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textView.text];
[mutableString insertString:text atIndex:textView.text.length];

if (mutableString.length <= desiredLenghtNumber) {
    return YES;

}
else  {
    return NO;
}
```

}

desiredLenghtNumber is the max number of letters, for example

```
int desiredLenghtNumber = 10;
```

of courde you need to set that textfield as delegate

```
textView.delgate = self;
```

and in .h file declare this delegate

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

Comment: what if the original poster wants the characters to stop when the cursor reaches the right side of the screen, versus a fixed number of characters?

Comment: there is method to get width of nsstring. Just check if width of nsstring is greater than width of textview. If yes - end of line.

Comment: is this the method that you are talking about? `sizeWithFont`? How should it be used if I want characters to fit exactly two lines? getting it's width would not be the solution I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I should answer this on my own.

I tried this code and this works for me.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
  NSString *myText = [textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];

  CGSize textSize = [myText sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(TEXTVIEW_WIDTH - 20, 10000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

  NSInteger strH = textSize.height;
  NSLog(@"String Size Height %i",strH);
  NSInteger maxHeight = 51;

    if (strH >= maxHeight)

    {
      return NO;
    }

   return YES;
}
```

I used 51 on my code here because when i check the value of the `strH` in `NSLog` i found out that 51 marks the start of third line. In which i will not allow the text to reach that height because I only need 2 lines of `UITextView` allowed in my app.

in `constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(TEXTVIEW_WIDTH - 20, 10000)` I subtracted 20px of my from my `UITextView` width to consider it's left and right margin.